# SAP UI5 file uploader element not working in IE11

Tags: javascript, sapui5

We are using SAP UI5 1.8.5 version. I can select file after clicking Browse button and upload attachments in Google Chrome. But in IE 11 (EDGE mode) when I click Browse button nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried checking the browser console for errors? You could perhaps try digging into the code using the developer tools to work out why it might be going wrong.

Comment: you may check if it's already properly working on [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com) IE.

Comment: Is this is a typo are you really using 1.8.5? If yes, you should definitely upgrade.

Comment: there are no errors in console. Nothing is triggering in JS page too. I am assuming that there could be problem with UI5 Libraries or CSS. Please advise which part should I check?

Comment: Yes, we are using 1.8.5 only  and version upgrade takes lot of time. Could you please suggest is there any alternative for this?

Comment: sap.ui.unified.FileUploader is only available since UI5 1.22. Something's wrong in what you're saying.

Comment: Issue is resolved. Since we are extending the width of FileUploader browse button is not working. After removing the width property of FileUPloader browse is working.